# Android Custom Slide Menu

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I created my custom Slide Menu. I used `FrameLayout` to show my custom slide menu. I have one problem. In a small divice my slide menu is working perfectly ,but in a large device fragment is not working. I can not show fragments components (for example buttons etc.).
This is my code:

```
<com.android.slidingmenuexample.MainLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/geo"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/geocell" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/menumm"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
public class MainLayout extends LinearLayout {

private static final int SLIDING_DURATION = 500;
private static final int QUERY_INTERVAL = 16;
int mainLayoutWidth;
private View menu;
private View content;
private static int menuRightMargin = 45;

private enum MenuState {
    HIDING, HIDDEN, SHOWING, SHOWN,
};

private int contentXOffset;
private MenuState currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;
private Scroller menuScroller = new Scroller(this.getContext(),
        new EaseInInterpolator());
private Runnable menuRunnable = new MenuRunnable();
private Handler menuHandler = new Handler();
int prevX = 0;
boolean isDragging = false;
int lastDiffX = 0;

public MainLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MainLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    mainLayoutWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    menuRightMargin = mainLayoutWidth * 50 / 100;
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    menu = this.getChildAt(0);
    content = this.getChildAt(1);
    content.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return MainLayout.this.onContentTouch(v, event);
        }
    });
    menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
        int bottom) {
    if (changed) {
        LayoutParams contentLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) content
                .getLayoutParams();
        contentLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
        contentLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth();
        LayoutParams menuLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) menu
                .getLayoutParams();
        menuLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
        menuLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth() - menuRightMargin;
    }
    menu.layout(left, top, right - menuRightMargin, bottom);
    content.layout(left + contentXOffset, top, right + contentXOffset,
            bottom);

}

public void toggleMenu() {

    if (currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING
            || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
        return;

    switch (currentMenuState) {
    case HIDDEN:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;
        menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        menuScroller.startScroll(0, 0, menu.getLayoutParams().width, 0,
                SLIDING_DURATION);
        break;
    case SHOWN:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
        menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, -contentXOffset, 0,
                SLIDING_DURATION);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
    this.invalidate();
}

protected class MenuRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean isScrolling = menuScroller.computeScrollOffset();
        adjustContentPosition(isScrolling);
    }
}

private void adjustContentPosition(boolean isScrolling) {
    int scrollerXOffset = menuScroller.getCurrX();

    content.offsetLeftAndRight(scrollerXOffset - contentXOffset);

    contentXOffset = scrollerXOffset;
    this.invalidate();
    if (isScrolling)
        menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
    else
        this.onMenuSlidingComplete();
}

private void onMenuSlidingComplete() {
    switch (currentMenuState) {
    case SHOWING:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWN;
        break;
    case HIDING:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;
        menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
}

protected class EaseInInterpolator implements Interpolator {
    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float t) {
        return (float) Math.pow(t - 1, 5) + 1;
    }

}

public boolean isMenuShown() {
    return currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWN;
}

public boolean onContentTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING
            || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
        return false;
    int curX = (int) event.getRawX();
    int diffX = 0;

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        prevX = curX;
        return true;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (!isDragging) {
            isDragging = true;
            menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        diffX = curX - prevX;
        if (contentXOffset + diffX <= 0) {
            diffX = -contentXOffset;
        } else if (contentXOffset + diffX > mainLayoutWidth
                - menuRightMargin) {
            diffX = mainLayoutWidth - menuRightMargin - contentXOffset;
        }
        content.offsetLeftAndRight(diffX);
        contentXOffset += diffX;
        this.invalidate();

        prevX = curX;
        lastDiffX = diffX;
        return true;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Up lastDiffX "
                + lastDiffX);

        if (lastDiffX > 0) {
            currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;
            menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0,
                    menu.getLayoutParams().width - contentXOffset, 0,
                    SLIDING_DURATION);
        } else if (lastDiffX < 0) {
            currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
            menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, -contentXOffset, 0,
                    SLIDING_DURATION);
        }
        menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
        this.invalidate();
        isDragging = false;
        prevX = 0;
        lastDiffX = 0;
        return true;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

And MainActivity java class

```
ublic class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

MainLayout mLayout;

ProgressDialog dialog;
Button btMenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mLayout = (MainLayout) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.activity_main, null);
    setContentView(mLayout);
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait... ", "Loading... ");
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


    btMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_menu);
    btMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Show/hide the menu
            toggleMenu(v);
        }
    });

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.this
                    .getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            Layout1 fragment = new Layout1();
            ft.add(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
            ft.commit();

            if (dialog != null) {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        }

    }, 10000);

}

public void toggleMenu(View v) {
    mLayout.toggleMenu();
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mLayout.isMenuShown()) {
        mLayout.toggleMenu();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}
I  have problem only large screen resolution. In a small and medium screen resolution program working perfect. if i touch layot in a large screen  then working perfect but if i click Button tu call toggleMenu function  then not working. in my option problem is toggleMenu function ,but i do not know what is a wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain different folders to support multiple screens in android.

The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

For more info refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: i created this folders and put my lauput xml files but not working.meybe problem is in source because if a touch in layout then working perfect but if i click  button to call  toggleMenu() function then not working